# initial AUTO_INCREMENT value for TypeORM PrimaryGeneratedColumn

Tags: typeorm

Is it possible to set the initial AUTO_INCREMENT value for the table with TypeORM PrimaryGeneratedColumn? I tried to read the documentation and code but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it directly from typeorm. But there is nothing stopping you to achieve the same in a migration script. For example, you can tweak the schema of creation migration script like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.my_seq
START WITH 1234
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
MAXVALUE 99999999
CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE public."my_schema" (
number integer DEFAULT nextval('public.my_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
name character varying NOT NULL);
```

References:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2153

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from the answer you can simply add to the migration script in the up section

```
await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE \`tableName\` auto_increment=1000000`);
```